# How can I filter the results returned by this PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I am using the following PowerShell script to return a list of connected USB Devices to the host computer:

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer Description,Service,DeviceID
```

I would like to filter the results based on the Description.  For instance, I would like to return only the Descriptions that are LIKE 'HASP%'.

What is the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet with the `-like` operator with `*` as the wildcard.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_USBControllerDevice |
    ForEach-Object {[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |
    Where-Object {$_.Description -like 'HASP*'} |
    Sort-Object Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID |
    Format-Table -GroupBy Manufacturer Description,Service,DeviceID
```

Also note that `?` and `where` are built-in aliases for the `Where-Object` cmdlet, since you are using other aliases in your question.